# jQuery Google Analytics tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to use jQuery to track downloads and other events on the webpage. It is difficult to debug this. The code below is not currently working. Assume the page has the jQuery library loading, and all of the XXXX's are replaced with the correct info. Any ideas? MUCH APPRECIATED!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'XXXXX.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'XXXXX.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    if (jQuery) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('a').click(function () {
                var $a = jQuery(this);
                var href = ($a.attr('href')) ? $a.attr('href') : '';
                if ((href.match(/^http/i)) && (!href.match(document.domain))) {
                    var category = 'outgoing - XXXX Landing';
                    var event = 'click - XXXX Landing';
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, event, href]);
                } else {
                    if (href.match(/.(doc|pdf|xls|ppt|zip|txt|vsd|vxd|js|css|rar|exe|wma|mov|avi|wmv|mp3)$/i)) {
                        var category = 'download - XXXX Landing';
                        var event = 'click - XXXX Landing';
                        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, event, href]);
                    } else {
                        if (href.match(/^mailto:/i)) {
                            var category = 'mailto - XXXX Landing';
                            var event = 'click - XXXX Landing';
                            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, event, href]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        if ('http:' == document.location.protocol) {
            ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        } else {
            ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        }
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: It's difficult to debug, partly, because it's so horribly formatted. You need to rectify this both in your question, and in your actual code if you've just copied and pasted it.

Comment: to debug first you should replace all **_gaq.push()** calls with **console.log() or alert();** - to see whether you jQuery code works properly

Comment: I've tried your code with `console.log` instead of `_gaq.push` and it worked just fine. Probably the `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'XXXXX.com']);` contains other domain than document.domain (e.g. you're testing on localhost). This mismatch can prevent google analytics tracking at all.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has Event Tracking built in.

For example, if you're trying to track a file download you could do something like this --

HTML:

```
<a href="sample.pdf" class="download">Click to download.</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a.download").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Files', 'Downloaded'])
});
```

Here is Google's official [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide). The guide will explain everything in much more detail for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use $.getScript to download and apply the GA code to the DOM rather than the long form stuff they give you as boilerplate. You'll also need that in the DOM before running the stuff where you set the tracking code, domain etc or _gaq won't be doing anything.